# How can I mock Elmah's ErrorSignal routine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, elmah

We're using ELMAH for handling errors in our ASP.Net MVC c# application and in our caught exceptions, we're doing something like this:

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
```

but when I try to unit test the caught exceptions, I get this message:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
```

How can I mock the FromCurrentContext() call?
Is there something else I should be doing instead?

FYI... We're currently using Moq and RhinoMocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since the `FromCurrentContext()` method is a static method you can't simply mock the call to it.  You do have two other options.

1. Since `FromCurrentContext()` internally makes a call to `HttpContext.Current` you can push a fake context in that.  For example:

   ```
   SimpleWorkerRequest request = new SimpleWorkerRequest(
       "/blah", @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah", "blah.html", null, new StringWriter());

   HttpContext.Current= new HttpContext(request);
   ```

   With this it should not throw the exception anymore since `HttpContext.Current` is not null.
2. Create a wrapper class around the call to Raise and just mock out the wrapper class.

   ```
   public class ErrorSignaler {

       public virtual void SignalFromCurrentContext(Exception e) {
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: This is an older question so maybe things have changed, but for Elmah 1.1, I had to also initialize the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance to a new HttpApplication() for this to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Another option is this:     
Dim req As System.Web.HttpRequest = New System.Web.HttpRequest(String.Empty, "https://www.domain.tld", Nothing)<br />
Dim res As System.Web.HttpResponse = New System.Web.HttpResponse(Nothing)<br />
System.Web.HttpContext.Current = New System.Web.HttpContext(req, res)<br />
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance = New System.Web.HttpApplication()<br />