# How to mockup Elmah?

Tags: .net, elmah

I seen this post but I am sort of confused by it.

[How can I mock Elmah's ErrorSignal routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019833/how-can-i-mock-elmahs-errorsignal-routine)

I am looking at option 2

```
Create a wrapper class around the call to Raise and just mock out the wrapper class.

public class ErrorSignaler {

public virtual void SignalFromCurrentContext(Exception e) {
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
}

}
```

I am kinda confused though by the fact that this does not seem to implement an interface and I am not really sure why it seems to be in place for some sort of inheritance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that you would use the `ErrorSignaler` class in your code to signal an error instead of invoking Elmah directly.  When running your code in unit tests, because `HttpContext.Current` is null, the Elmah component won't be used, and there won't be any null reference exceptions.

You could also create an `ErrorSignaler` interface:

```
public interface IErrorSignaler
{
    void SignalFromCurrentContext(Exception e);
}
```

That way the implementation used to implement `IErrorSignaler` can be mocked in the unit tests if required.

Comment: Ya that's what I ended up doing then I mocked it. I just was wondering the guy had "Virtual"

Comment: That would allow him to subclass the ErrorSignaler to add even more behaviour to the `Signal` method.  That flexibility could be useful in some situtations.